# Savitzky–Golay filter for 2D images

Tags: image, filter, 2d

I would like to ask about Savitzky–Golay filter on 2D-images.

What are the best coefficient and order to choose for finding local details in the image.

Moreover, if someone has an explanation for coefficients and the orders one the 2D-images, it would be perfect.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out this website:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter#Two-dimensional_convolution_coefficients

**UPDATE:** (Thank you for the suggestion, @Rasclatt)

Which has been reproduced here:

Two-dimensional smoothing and differentiation can also be applied to tables of data values, such as intensity values in a photographic image which is composed of a rectangular grid of pixels.[16] [17] The trick is to transform part of the table into a row by a simple ordering of the indices of the pixels. Whereas the one-dimensional filter coefficients are found by fitting a polynomial in the subsidiary variable, z to a set of m data points, the two-dimensional coefficients are found by fitting a polynomial in subsidiary variables v and w to a set of m × m data points. The following example, for a bicubic polynomial and m = 5, illustrates the process, which parallels the process for the one dimensional case, above.[18]

[image]
[image]

The square of 25 data values, d1 − d25

[image]

becomes a vector when the rows are placed one after another.

[image]

The Jacobian has 10 columns, one for each of the parameters a00 − a03 and 25 rows, one for each pair of v and w values. Each row has the form

[image]

The convolution coefficients are calculated as

[image]

The first row of C contains 25 convolution coefficients which can be multiplied with the 25 data values to provide a smoothed value for the central data point (13) of the 25.

Answer (score 0):

check out the below links which use SURE(Stein's unbiased risk estimator) to minimizes the mean squared error between your estimate and the image. This method is useful for denoising and data smoothing.

this link is for optimization of parameters for 1D Savitzky Golay Filter(this will be helpful to understand the 2D part)
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6331560/?part=1

this link is for optimization of parameters of 2D Savitzky Golay Filter
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6738095/